# Paypal: use Magento product ID instead of SKU

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I've recently started using PayPal as an alternative option for customers and I noticed that on the PayPal site that the products SKU is being displayed. For continuity of my website, I would like to display the product ID instead.

I have done searches with grep in `/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal` to find `getSku` but cant find anything.

Where does the Magento PayPal module get the product SKU? and How can I replace it with the ID? (`$_product->getId()`) ?

Comment: Pls go file \app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Cart.php and find $salesItem->getSku()

Comment: Post as an answer I will test later thank you

Comment: I put getId but it generates a number other than the product ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First move file `app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Cart.php` in local folder or override model in local

After replace code **from**

```
protected function _addRegularItem(Varien_Object $salesItem)
{
    if ($this->_salesEntity instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
        $qty = (int) $salesItem->getQtyOrdered();
        $amount = (float) $salesItem->getBasePrice();
        // TODO: nominal item for order
    } else {
        $qty = (int) $salesItem->getTotalQty();
        $amount = $salesItem->isNominal() ? 0 : (float) $salesItem->getBaseCalculationPrice();
    }
    // workaround in case if item subtotal precision is not compatible with PayPal (.2)
    $subAggregatedLabel = '';
    if ($amount - round($amount, 2)) {
        $amount = $amount * $qty;
        $subAggregatedLabel = ' x' . $qty;
        $qty = 1;
    }

    // aggregate item price if item qty * price does not match row total
    if (($amount * $qty) != $salesItem->getBaseRowTotal()) {
        $amount = (float) $salesItem->getBaseRowTotal();
        $subAggregatedLabel = ' x' . $qty;
        $qty = 1;
    }

    return $this->addItem($salesItem->getName() . $subAggregatedLabel, $qty, $amount, $salesItem->getSku());
}
```

**To**

```
protected function _addRegularItem(Varien_Object $salesItem)
{
    if ($this->_salesEntity instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order) {
        $qty = (int) $salesItem->getQtyOrdered();
        $amount = (float) $salesItem->getBasePrice();
        // TODO: nominal item for order
    } else {
        $qty = (int) $salesItem->getTotalQty();
        $amount = $salesItem->isNominal() ? 0 : (float) $salesItem->getBaseCalculationPrice();
    }
    // workaround in case if item subtotal precision is not compatible with PayPal (.2)
    $subAggregatedLabel = '';
    if ($amount - round($amount, 2)) {
        $amount = $amount * $qty;
        $subAggregatedLabel = ' x' . $qty;
        $qty = 1;
    }

    // aggregate item price if item qty * price does not match row total
    if (($amount * $qty) != $salesItem->getBaseRowTotal()) {
        $amount = (float) $salesItem->getBaseRowTotal();
        $subAggregatedLabel = ' x' . $qty;
        $qty = 1;
    }

    return $this->addItem($salesItem->getName() . $subAggregatedLabel, $qty, $amount, $salesItem->getProductId());
}
```